# Why behavior of NameValueCollection is different?

Tags: c#, asp.net, namevaluecollection

```
NameValueCollection x = new NameValueCollection(Request.QueryString);
string x1 = x.ToString();
NameValueCollection y = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Request.QueryString.ToString());
string y1 = y.ToString();
```

when I execute above code, value of x1 and y1 become

```
x1="System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection"
y1="abc=1&xyz=2"   //url pass to controller is 'localhost/first/getresult/?abc=1&xyz=2'
```

I don't understand why the value of `x1 and y1 is different`. I checked the documentation of `ParseQueryString()` and it show that it `return NameValueCollection` and I don't get any other information.

So, I don't understand why behavior is different of `x` and `y`.

Comment: Did you check the types of `x` and `y`. It seems to me that `y` is of a type derived from `NameValueCollection`. `NameValueCollection` and its base class don't implement `ToString()`, thatswhy `x.ToString()` returns the type name. Since `y.ToString()` returns something different `y` must be of a derived type that implements its own `ToString()` method.

Comment: HttpUtility.ParseQueryString return a type of HttpValueCollection which overwrite the .ToString method of its base class NameValueCollection.
Here is the documentation.
https://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Web/R/ad077f34023fd2eb.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case of [`HttpUtility.ParseQueryString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046(v=vs.110).aspx) an instance of the class [`HttpValueCollection`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/HttpValueCollection.cs) is returned([source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/httpserverutility.cs,8c392029e2dd33f5,references)) which inherits from `NameValueCollection`. Obviously this classs overrides `ToString` meaningfully as opposed to `NameValueCollection` which inherits `ToString` from object, hence just diplays the full-type name.

That's not mentioned in `ParseQueryString` because `HttpValueCollection` is `internal`. They don't want you to use this type and you should not rely on this type being returned.

Here's the [source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/HttpValueCollection.cs,ad077f34023fd2eb,references) of `ToString` in `HttpValueCollection`:

```
public override String ToString() {
    return ToString(true);
}

internal virtual String ToString(bool urlencoded) {
    return ToString(urlencoded, null);
}

internal virtual String ToString(bool urlencoded, IDictionary excludeKeys) {
    int n = Count;
    if (n == 0)
        return String.Empty;

    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
    String key, keyPrefix, item;
    bool ignoreViewStateKeys = (excludeKeys != null && excludeKeys[Page.ViewStateFieldPrefixID] != null);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        key = GetKey(i);

        // Review: improve this... Special case hack for __VIEWSTATE#
        if (ignoreViewStateKeys && key != null && key.StartsWith(Page.ViewStateFieldPrefixID, StringComparison.Ordinal)) continue;
        if (excludeKeys != null && key != null && excludeKeys[key] != null)
            continue;
        if (urlencoded)
            key = UrlEncodeForToString(key);
        keyPrefix = (key != null) ? (key + "=") : String.Empty;

        string[] values = GetValues(i);

        if (s.Length > 0)
            s.Append('&');

        if (values == null || values.Length == 0) {
            s.Append(keyPrefix);
        }
        else if (values.Length == 1) {
            s.Append(keyPrefix);
            item = values[0];
            if (urlencoded)
                item = UrlEncodeForToString(item);
            s.Append(item);
        }
        else {
            for (int j = 0; j < values.Length; j++) {
                if (j > 0)
                    s.Append('&');
                s.Append(keyPrefix);
                item = values[j];
                if (urlencoded)
                    item = UrlEncodeForToString(item);
                s.Append(item);
            }
        }
    }

    return s.ToString();
}
```